# How can draw a rectangle inside a cell from GridView, I using webforms c#

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

The idea is to change the name of the color in the color column for a rectangle with that color, filling the gridview with information stored in the database.

I need to do that column change for each row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnRowDataBound event of the gridview to change the contents of the cells programmatically.

Just at a quick google I found this tutorial with an example of making a visual change to a cell based on data in the row:
http://www.tutorialspanel.com/rowdatabound-event-gridview-asp-net/
"Example 1: highlight the row in red if salary is equal or above $10.000" is conceptually similar to what you're trying to do I think.